# Time differences between making threads and processes

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

```
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import os
def MyTask():
    time.sleep(2)
t0 = time.time()
threads = []
for i in range(10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=MyTask)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
t1 = time.time()
print("Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: {} seconds".format(t1-t0))
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

t2 = time.time()
procs = []
for i in range(10):
    process = Process(target=MyTask)
    process.start()
    procs.append(process)
t3 = time.time()
print("Total Time for Creating 10 Processes: {} seconds".format(t3-t2))
for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

I should compare the time between making threads and processes.
But there is a problem.
Here is a result.

```
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.0019941329956054688 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Processes: 0.06481027603149414 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.04188799858093262 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.01695418357849121 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.01595759391784668 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.003989696502685547 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.003989696502685547 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.001995563507080078 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.0019948482513427734 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.0019948482513427734 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.0009980201721191406 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.0009975433349609375 seconds
```

I only want one total time for creating threads and processes each.
I think this is because of multiprocessing. But, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I think you should be printing `after` joining all the threads, no?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you didn't see the

```
RuntimeError: 
    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

If you use the freeze_support() it runs fine

```
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
import time
import os


def MyTask():
    time.sleep(2)


def main():
    t0 = time.time()
    threads = []

    for i in range(10):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=MyTask)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    t1 = time.time()
    print("Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: {} seconds".format(t1-t0))

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    t2 = time.time()
    procs = []

    for i in range(10):
        process = Process(target=MyTask)
        process.start()
        procs.append(process)

    t3 = time.time()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    print("Total Time for Creating 10 Processes: {} seconds".format(t3-t2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

Result

```
Total Time for Creating 10 Threads: 0.0020024776458740234 seconds
Total Time for Creating 10 Processes: 0.10802268981933594 seconds

Process finished with exit code 0
```